# How to assign the variable value to the input type "file"

Tags: javascript, jquery

Hi I have small requirement, is there any way to update variable value to the input type file value (Browse).

```
<input type="hidden" value="Testfile - CSV - 100 rows.csv"   id="filePathHdnID" name="filePathHdn" />

<input class="fileType" name="uploadfile" type="file" id="idUploadFile"/>
```

Here is jquery code what I tried

```
$("#idUploadFile").val($("#filePathHdnID").val());
```

Please share me your ideas, sorry if it is confused.

Comment: I think you can set the value but would be of no use . As when you select any file by `type=file` then it captures the path as well . But here assigning just the value won't work .

Answer (score 1):

Looking at your requirement, you want to set a *default file path* for the `file input control`. 
Unfortunately, this is a very **common** requirement that every client wants, but *not possible* using javascript because of **Security Reasons**.

> **What if possible:** You as a developer can modify the file input and post it to server, and the actual user will not get notified. Any
>   feature/requirement of language that creates a security threat is kept **closed**
>   for developers :)

Answer (score 0):

You cannot change the value of file input.
Because file object created once you has a file selected, and

File object that contain useful information about the file.

name
The file's name as a **read-only** string. This is just the file name, and does not include any path information.

here the file name is the value you want to change.

[doc](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Using_files_from_web_applications#Getting_information_about_selected_file(s))